# how to find unique letters in string

Tags: python

I have to create a program that generates a five digit number which a user has to guess by getting different clues like how many digits they have correct and how many are in the correct position.

The function i have written out now it to find the unique letters aka the  letters that each string has in common. Now this works if the length is exactly 5 letters. But i need to have a statement written out (this is too short or long) when the user exceeds a length of 5 or is lower than 5. It says this but counts what is right and adds it to the previous number. This shouldnt be there. Also the numbers shouldnt add only state the right amount in that attempt. Heres it visually:

```
rannum remove : 24510
enter number: 24511
4
enter number: 12
this is too short
6
```

heres the code:

```
while not userguess:
    guess = str(input("enter number: "))
    if len(guess) < 5:
        print("this is too short")
    for i in list(set(secretString) & set(guess)):
        uniquedigits_found += 1
    print(uniquedigits_found)
```

is there anyway to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try resetting your unique digits variable in each iteration of the while loop, and separate the for loop to check matching digits in an else statement:

```
while not userguess:
    uniquedigits_found = 0
    guess = str(input("enter number nerd: "))
    if len(guess) < 5:
        print("this is too short")
    elif len(guess) > 5:
        print("this is too long")
    else:
        for i in list(set(secretString) & set(guess)):
            uniquedigits_found += 1
        print(uniquedigits_found)
```